# Excel pivot row filter to column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, which has 3 row filters (tester, Jig, measurement).
I need to copy the entire pivot to raw data to another sheet.
How can i transform pivot row filters to pasted as column vhen i hit paste values?

Example:

```
Tester 1
   Jig1
      measurement 1
      measurement 2
      measurement 3
   Jig2
      measurement 1
      measurement 2
      measurement 3
Tester 2 ....
```

I need the data in the following format:

```
Tester 1 | Jig1 | measurement 1
Tester 1 | Jig1 | measurement 2
Tester 1 | Jig1 | measurement 3
Tester 1 | Jig2 | measurement 1
Tester 1 | Jig2 | measurement 2
Tester 1 | Jig2 | measurement 3
Tester 2 ...
```

The bar (|) simulate next cell in excel.
How can i archieve this?
The pivot has 4K rows!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
1. Click on the Pivot table header
2. Click on the Design tab on the top menu
3. The Layout tab contains Report Layout icon, click on it
4. Click on **Show In Tabular Form**, and **Repeat All Item Labels**
5. Click on Layout -> Grand Totals -> Off for Rows and Columns
6. Click on Layout -> Subtotals -> Do Not Show Subtotals
```

Then you can copy the table.

BR, Peter